# Определить дату определенного дня недели по другой дате

Tags: postgresql, дата

Есть запрос к БД PosgreSQL:

```
SELECT some_date, EXTRACT(DOW FROM some_date) from orders
WHERE some_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-14';
```

Соответственно, выпадает список дат и их дней недели.
Необходимо найти дату предыдущего понедельника от выпадающей даты.
Например: 08.01.2022 (это суббота) - необходимо, чтобы отобразилась дата понедельника, который был до указанной субботы, в нашем случае это 03.01.2022.

Не очень понятно даже с чего начать поступать к этому уравнению.

Comment: а вручную ты бы как "поступал" к этому уравнению?

Comment: имея на руках интересующий номер дня недели и день недели нужной даты вычисляете разницу в днях. И эту разницу вычитаете из даты

Answer (score 1):

Если необходим именно предшествующий понедельник, то для этой частной задачи достаточно применить [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
melkij=> select date_trunc('week', date '2022-01-08'); -- в субботу даст пн
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2022-01-03 00:00:00+03
(1 строка)

melkij=> select date_trunc('week', date '2022-01-03'); -- для понедельника вернёт себя же
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2022-01-03 00:00:00+03
(1 строка)
```

Answer (score 0):

Это пример решения на сгенерированных данных:

```
select 
    current_date-t.a as today,
    (EXTRACT(DOW FROM current_date-t.a)-1)::integer as day_ned,
    case
        when (EXTRACT(DOW FROM current_date-t.a)-1)::integer < 0
        then current_date-t.a - (EXTRACT(DOW FROM current_date-t.a)+6)::integer
        when (EXTRACT(DOW FROM current_date-t.a)-1)::integer >= 0
        then current_date-t.a - (EXTRACT(DOW FROM current_date-t.a)-1)::integer
    end as last_monday
    from generate_series(0, 1000, 1) as t(a);
```

А вот это должно помочь Вам:

```
select 
    some_date as today,
    (EXTRACT(DOW FROM some_date)-1)::integer as day_ned,
    case
        when (EXTRACT(DOW FROM some_date)-1)::integer < 0
        then some_date - (EXTRACT(DOW FROM some_date)+6)::integer
        when (EXTRACT(DOW FROM some_date)-1)::integer >= 0
        then some_date - (EXTRACT(DOW FROM some_date)-1)::integer
    end as last_monday
    from orders;
```